# "The website cannot display the page" error when accessing the SSRS Report Manager 2012

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to connect to a SSRS 2012 Report Manager on a Win Server 2012 server.

I'm getting "The website cannot display the page" error. Can't figure out why.

I've tried the following things:

- Browsing either to the computer's name url and either to the computer's network ip address
- Changing the service login type.
- Running IE as Administrator

**I can connect to the Web Service and I can view reports through it.**

I'm connecting with a Domain Admin account.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the event log for any relevant information?

Comment: Which event log? I would appreciate guidance.

Comment: OK. I checked the event log. It appears that I had stuck in the Managers library a Dll which couldn't be loaded (and isn't needed or belongs there).

Thank you, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The answer was indeed detected in the Windows Event Log. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the SSRS host as a trusted site in the browser fixed this for me.